# $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions

Please help me to find $a,b,c,d$ such that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ ?
I take $a,b$ for example $2,3$ to find $c,d$ but I get stuck on this. I know that is diophantine equation , but I am unable to find suitable $a,b,c,d$ .
$$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} ,a,c\neq 0$$
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which algebraic structure do $a,b,c$ and $d$ belong to?

Comment: Are you looking for all $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy this?  Just one specific example?  A specific example where $a=2$ and $b=3$?  What does "I can't find suite $a,b,b,c$" mean?

Comment: I think $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is always strictly _between_ $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger That's only true if $a,b,c,d$ are positive.

Comment: $$ad(b+d)+cb(b+d)=(a+c)bd$$ $$ad^2=-cb^2$$

Comment: @Naive:thanks for your notification : $$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: I'm guessing this is for normal addition and not farey addition ?

Comment: If $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd=k, k=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$$ So, we need $$ad=bc$$

Comment: @individ Note, too, that since $\gcd (a,b)=1=\gcd (c,d)$ (assuming that the OP wants the terms in reduced form) we must have $a=-c,b=d$  (the case $b=-d$ is ruled out by the form of the right hand).

Comment: @Naive :It is right but not such trivial solution !!

Comment: If your question was $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ then one of the it's solution is $a=d=f_{n+1}$ and $b=c=f_n$ where $f_n$ is the $n$th term of Fibonacci sequence because we have $\phi -\frac{1}{\phi}-1=0$. Maybe helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could get, hope it helps :)

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$

For any $h,\;k,\;j\in\mathbb{Z},\;j\ne 0,h\ne-1$

Let $\left\{a= k,b= j,c=- h^2 -k,d= h j\right\}$

we get $\dfrac{k}{j}-\dfrac{h k}{j}=\dfrac{k-h^2 k}{h j+j}$

indeed $\dfrac{k-hk}{j}=\dfrac{k(1+h)(1-h)}{j(h+1)}$

and finally $\dfrac{k-hk}{j}=\dfrac{k(1-h)}{j}$

**Edit**.

I am not sure that these are *ALL* the solutions

Comment: Thank you for your simple representation. خسروتاش

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac ab+\frac cd-\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{ad^2+b^2c}{bd(b+d)}
$$